# Combining 10 queries into one PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a complete PHP newbie (as in I wrote my first line two weeks ago so I might not see what's right in front of me).

I'm doing a bar chart for a project of mine. I have a table (show_score) with scores out of 10 (column: score) and a show_id (column show_id).

I need the number of scores for a show_id :

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mytvbox', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM show_score WHERE show_id = 40');
$stmt->execute(array('show_id' => $show_id));


$count = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $count. "number of scores<br>";
```

Then I need the number of score for each number and the percentage it represents on the total number of scores (here for 8)

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM show_score WHERE show_id = 40 AND score = 8');
$stmt->execute(array('show_id' => $show_id));


$countscore_8 = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $countscore_8 . "number of 8<br>";   //nombre total de 8 sur la serie 


if ($countscore_8 == 0)  //if no score then no pixels for you
{ echo "0px"; }
else {


$division = $countscore_8 / $count; //finding ration
$percentage = $division * 100;  //finding percentage of score 8
$pixels = 180;   //base pixels
$finalpixels = ($percentage / 100) * $pixels; 
echo $finalpixels . "px"; //number of pixels in the bar
}
```

My issue is that I have to to a query for each score to find the number of pixels the bar in the chart will have. Is there a way to output percentage for each score in a single query ?

To make it a bit more clear, let's suppose my table has this:

```
show_id = 40, score = 5
show_id = 40, score = 5
show_id = 40, score = 10
show_id = 40, score = 10
```

I need

```
score 1:  0% / 0px
score 2:  0% / 0px
score 3:  0% / 0px
score 4:  0% / 0px
score 5: 50% / 90px
score 6:  0% / 0px
score 7:  0% / 0px
score 8:  0% / 0px
score 9:  0% / 0px
score 10:50% / 90px
```

Hope this somehow makes sense.

Comment: `SELECT score, COUNT(score) AS amount FROM show_score WHERE show_id = 40 GROUP BY score ORDER BY score ASC` should get you all non-zero scores. After that, simple math.

Comment: Great, thank you! Guess I need me a proper SQL lesson.

Comment: You also need to indent your code properly. ;) Left-aligned code is unreadable.

Comment: @Tomalak: Thank you, will do.
Also have another question, to properly implement this, I would need to have my non-zero scores, in my array, how could I do that ?

Comment: If you have another question, click the "Ask a question" button again. It's best not to ask multiple questions in one post.